# How can I align multiple nodes horizontally to another node / other nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to align either one node A (see first `center`-environment in MWE) or multiple  nodes A+AA (see second `center`-environment in MWE) to another set of nodes (B-F) so that they are centered to each other.

How can I do that?

Note:

- Currently I still use the method via anchoring on the left side and adding a manual shift into x-direction which gets me some satisfactory result, but it does not look great.
- In the first `center` environment, one could quickly decide to align the A and D but this is a somewhat bad example because very often the nodes are not of the same width.

### Picture

[image]

### MWE

```
\documentclass[
12pt,
a4paper
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
    calc,
    intersections,
    positioning
}

\tikzset{
    framedAAA/.style={
        rectangle,
        draw=black,
        very thick
    },
}

\listfiles

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
        \node[framedAAA] (nodeA) {A};
        \node[framedAAA, below=of nodeA.west, anchor=west, xshift=-2cm] (nodeB) {b};
        \node[framedAAA, right=of nodeB.east, anchor=west] (nodeC) {c};
        \node[framedAAA, right=of nodeC.east, anchor=west] (nodeD) {d};
        \node[framedAAA, right=of nodeD.east, anchor=west] (nodeE) {e};
        \node[framedAAA, right=of nodeE.east, anchor=west] (nodeF) {F};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
    \node[framedAAA] (nodeA) {A};
    \node[framedAAA, right=of nodeA] (nodeA) {AA};
    \node[framedAAA, below=of nodeA.west, anchor=west, xshift=-2cm] (nodeB) {b};
    \node[framedAAA, right=of nodeB.east, anchor=west] (nodeC) {c};
    \node[framedAAA, right=of nodeC.east, anchor=west] (nodeD) {d};
    \node[framedAAA, right=of nodeD.east, anchor=west] (nodeE) {e};
    \node[framedAAA, right=of nodeE.east, anchor=west] (nodeF) {F};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thought: One could use `\draw ($(nodeB.west)!0.5!(nodeF.east)$) coordinate (middlenodeLOWER);\draw[red] (middlenodeLOWER.north) -- ([yshift=20pt]middlenodeLOWER.north);\draw[red] (nodeA.south) -- ([yshift=-4pt]nodeA.south);` for the first center-environment. Then aligning them--literally--point by point would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use `matrix` nodes, and try using global declarations as `every node/.style=framedAAA`  to avoid repeat in every node. Add the `matrix` library with `\usetikzlibrary{matrix}`. This simplifies the code. Here is my code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,positioning,matrix}

\tikzset{
    framedAAA/.style={
        rectangle,
        draw=black,
        very thick,
    },
}

\listfiles

\begin{document}
\begin{center} 
  \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
    \matrix[matrix of nodes,column sep=1cm,every node/.style=framedAAA,name=nodeBF]
    {
    B & C & D & E & F\\
    };   
    \node[framedAAA,above=5mm of nodeBF] (nodeA) {A}; 
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
% Here my second alignment (both nodes of `matrix` type)   
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
    \matrix[matrix of nodes,column sep=1cm,every node/.style=framedAAA,name=nodeBF]
    {
      B & C & D & E & F\\
    };
    \matrix[matrix of nodes,column sep=1cm,every node/.style=framedAAA,name=nodeAAA,above=5mm of nodeBF]
    {
      A & AA\\
    };    
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

and here the result

[image]

Comment: This is easier to understand imho. Damnit, I just changed all the bits to nodes earlier. Not going to put it all into a matrix again, but thank you nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to put the nodes `B - F` in a `scope`, and use the `local bounding box` of this scope.

The first example, with only one node `A` is really easy to solve this way:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
    % We put the nodes in a scope, with bounding box `scope1`
    \begin{scope}[local bounding box=scope1]
        \node[framedAAA] (nodeB) {b};
        \node[framedAAA, right=of nodeB.east, anchor=west] (nodeC) {c};
        \node[framedAAA, right=of nodeC.east, anchor=west] (nodeD) {d};
        \node[framedAAA, right=of nodeD.east, anchor=west] (nodeE) {e};
        \node[framedAAA, right=of nodeE.east, anchor=west] (nodeF) {F};
    \end{scope}
    % Simply put the node above `scope1`
    \node[framedAAA, above=of scope1.north] (nodeA) {A};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

When we want to align two sets of several nodes, we can use a ghost scope that will help compute the size of the second set of nodes `A-AA`, and then shift the real nodes appropriately:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
    \begin{scope}[local bounding box=scope1]
        \node[framedAAA] (nodeB) {b};
        \node[framedAAA, right=of nodeB.east, anchor=west] (nodeC) {c};
        \node[framedAAA, right=of nodeC.east, anchor=west] (nodeD) {d};
        \node[framedAAA, right=of nodeD.east, anchor=west] (nodeE) {e};
        \node[framedAAA, right=of nodeE.east, anchor=west] (nodeF) {F};
    \end{scope}

    % Ghost scope above the nodes B-F
    \begin{scope}[local bounding box=ghost, shift={($(scope1.north)+(0,1cm)$)}]
        \node[white] (ghostA) {A};
        \node[white, right=of ghostA] (ghostAA) {AA};
    \end{scope}

    % This scope is shifted to the left, so that it is centered
    \begin{scope}[local bounding box=scope2, shift={($2*(ghostA)-(ghost)$)}]
        \node[framedAAA] (nodeA) {A};
        \node[framedAAA, right=of nodeA] (nodeA) {AA};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

To explain the formula `2*(ghostA)-(ghost)`, it is equivalent to `(ghostA) - ((ghost)-(ghostA))`, which means that the node `nodeA` will be shifted from `ghostA` by the distance between `ghostA` and the center of the ghost scope. This will place the center of `scope2` at `ghostA`, which was aligned with the center of `scope1`.

As you see, my solution when there are several nodes `A-AA` is quite complex. I would be interested in a simpler solution.